# IAM Policy not working for AWS MediaPackage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-media-live, aws-mediaservices, aws-mediapackage

I am trying to work with AWS Elemental MediaPackage and AWS Elemental MediaLive. I'm have a good amount of experience with AWS and IAM Roles. I've attached a Full Access policy for both services but somehow I still do not have access. I'm trying to figure out what I am missing.

[image: AWS MediaPackage Admin no access]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is **not about your IAM user** permissions which you've posted in the question. The error is about some **IAM role** which does not have necessary permissions.

Since you removed the name of the role from the first screenshot, I can't comment which role is it exactly. So you have to go to the role in IAM console, and **add the permissions missing** which are also listed in the error message.

Comment: Thank you so much you're a life saver. It was the IAM Role not the IAM User.